# How do I solve error Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, webpack, angular.json

**Angular Project details:**
"@angular/cli": "^15.2.10"
"swiper": "^8.4.7",

Am using swiper in my angular project and after migrating to angular 15 getting the error

```
"./node_modules/swiper/swiper.min.css?ngGlobalStyle:13:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (13:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders"
```

This error can be temporarily solved by commenting the line out from the particular file node_modules/swiper/swiper.min.css but given this error is of node modules every time we do "npm i" it persists.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "app",
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",

          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "@firebase",
              "@angular/fire",
              "rxjs",
              "firebase",
              "@firebase/app",
              "@firebase/remote-config",
              "@firebase/performance",
              "@firebase/functions",
              "@firebase/firestore",
              "@firebase/database",
              "@firebase/auth",
              "@firebase/util",
              "@firebase/component",
              "jquery",
              "firebase/app",
              "css-element-queries",
              "markdown-it",
              "lottie-web/build/player/lottie_svg",
              "src/app/components/terms-and-policy/terms-and-policy.component",
              "crypto-js"
            ],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/robot.txt",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "./"
              },
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/service-worker.js",
              "src/robot.txt",
              "src/sitemap-pages.xml",
              "src/sitemap.xsl",
              {
                "glob": "workbox-sw.js",
                "input": "node_modules/workbox-sw/build/",
                "output": "./workbox-500"
              },
              {
                "glob": "workbox-core.prod.js",
                "input": "node_modules/workbox-core/build/",
                "output": "./workbox-500"
              },
              {
                "glob": "workbox-precaching.prod.js",
                "input": "node_modules/workbox-precaching/build/",
                "output": "./workbox-500"
              },
              {
                "glob": "workbox-window.prod.mjs",
                "input": "node_modules/workbox-window/build/",
                "output": "./workbox-500"
              },
              "src/OneSignalSDKWorker.js",
              "src/OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/customTheme.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icons.min.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css",
                "inject": false
              }
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "node_modules"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js",
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js",
              "node_modules/clipboard/dist/clipboard.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/Segment.js",
              "src/assets/js/GTM.js",
              "src/assets/js/typeform.js",
              "src/OneSignalSDKWorker.js",
              "src/OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js"
            ],
            "webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json",
            "aot": true,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": true,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "index": {
                "input": "src/index.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": {
                "hidden": true,
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": true
              },
              "namedChunks": true,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "40mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "50kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
            },
            "emulate": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.function-emulate.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
              "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./webpack.config.js"
      },
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "emulate": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:emulate"
            },
            "ci": {}
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css",
                "inject": false
              }
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "node_modules"
              ]
            },
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/robots.txt",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "./"
              },
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "progress": false,
              "watch": false
            }
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:ci"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-build": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit",
    "analytics": false
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

After adding webpack.config.js and running "ng build" it gives following error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: path is not defined
```

Following installation are done :

- npm install sass-loader sass --save-dev
- npm install --save-dev @angular-builders/custom-webpack
- npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
- npm install --save-dev webpack

Used webpack.config.js file to solve this error.

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
module.exports = {
        entry: './src/main.ts',
  
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www')
    },
  
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'styles.css'
      }),
    ],
  
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use : [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        {
                                loader: 'style-loader',
                        },
                        {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {
                                        sourceMap: true,
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                loader: 'sass-loader',
                                options: {
                                    implementation: require('sass'),
                                },
                        }
                        
                    ]
            }
        ]
    },
  };
```

changed angular.json file to include webpack.config.js while building

Is this approach a correct way to solve this issue ,if not any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you reference swiper styles anywhere in your app's style files (e.g. styles.scss)?

Comment: yes @Shlang am calling swiper in some places in project like `@import "swiper/css";
@import "swiper/css/effect-cards";` in scss files.

Comment: Do you also import `src/assets/css/styles.css` in some of your `ts` files?

Comment: No @Shlang I use a global.scss file and not styles.css

Comment: Yeah, anyway. This error usually occurs when you try to import scss as es module in some of your ts files as this is not supported.